# How to augment imported json file in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I am importing a JSON file in my TypeScript code (using version 4.0.0+) and I need to augment its definition.

```
import catalog from '../../../data/app.catalog.json';
```

I have created a file `global.d.ts` at the TS root of the project and augmented as:

```
declare module '*.catalog.json' {
  interface Variant {
    id: string;
    props: {
      [k: string]: string;
    };
    svg: string;
  }

  const value: Variant;

  export default value;
}
```

However, TypeScript doesn't respect this and treats the type of `catalog` as empty object `{}`.

On a side note, when I change the extension of the file from `json` to something else, the module augmentation works fine. Somehow, it is using its own inference for `json` files instead of picking up the definition I have provided.

Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: remove `.` after `*`, i.e. `declare module '*.catalog.json'` -> `declare module '*catalog.json'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared your JSON file, but—presumably—you just want to inform TS that your JSON is actually a supertype of the type that it's been inferred as (e.g. string keys for `json.props`), or that it's a type that's at least compatible with the actual data.

If that's true, then you can do it with an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), like this:

```ts
function assertIsType <T>(value: unknown): asserts value is T {
  if (/* value is not the shape of T */) throw new Error('Invalid type');
  // else value is T and function exits cleanly, implicitly returning void/undefined
}
```

After invoking the function on a `value`, `value` will be the type intersection `typeof value & T`. If `typeof value` is completely incompatible with `T`, then the compiler will not allow the invocation using the generic you supply for `T`.

> #### Warning:
>
> If you don't actually validate in the function body the type that you are asserting, you are *lying* to the compiler, and it will believe you. I'm going to do this in the example below:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PQkAgMQSwGwUwFxgHTOK9aAmBDALjsDgA7HIDG+OMA9gObIBWAzjQHYBQ4AQnJQK7M4YAJ41+YLFCxsA5HjDMAFjgBOwsf1Vgc5PP2pgAUgGUA8gDkwAM1hwANGACSsmDDABbHAGth-YjpgeCLEcFzAQTRg6sTqQmwKAO4qCgAqJmBQbNZwqsyZCnhRAEbCWYHBxFCU7szkcGxqUDQIHByVwk7ZuepYRqxsYAC8YADeHGCZWEjMeKpZdADcE2CxNMTMSOOTkzBQeLnUAIwzcwvLO2B7B6rUAEyn82xLK7v7hzAAzI-nr2DgcDw5FQyBWAF8Lv8IswAG50H7PRZQsAAGUBsnyzBwIiCSig+XxcgU5U02l0+kMpksHAhbXCoEgdiQaA8NCw-HgyDwzHCzjYszgOCwYBo1lxwnJBncUA8xBoqgUpQEQlx+PFqxg2LoqnEbGFWBocGYRMU-jlCs8HLwUGI8Bsdk2vJl5oUlAItDoNh1HjAsgw-uwVCIpAoVA9TAGsmWWD4mvUYHI7FmCbD9CQXRyql6-XYy15AHV2PIwIl5d4wEqcIJhKKwOlMt08ld3rd3L4RI63dR6Mg1htkKwPHAAAo6gIjDE0IdgGHUfhwKP-ABUf0ua7AAD0t9utxxR+tcsFfYOR2PZJJDfk2DQFHAAB74hTsIIhYSyUbNm7HBFLT8fB6KGciJ-q23yAU8v5gn6AAUdyfJ8ACcACUYBLsAbRZDc1i6MIABqTQ4AkYwrNIP6Qn2mxgAASnw8pYAAPLMEGOExCwAHyQrC8Lgb8YJtNY-BsHozSDDgzBCAqTjMKkr5gPRqRsdBs4wPOSCCd416JGwSFIGJEncjOc5lPkqRjHxHB6YeUkyaE9H4fMhF4IpXYekhywufQSLgB5npqppL6hGA0EZj0cB9AMYAAGRgPZUCOUhHA+b2Y7MAOU6nuswzHulhkqQuXkRDQ3htIm-I0JyHrQUlXFucigkxrYbBhYlqYMFxBU8c8jjFPwhR4gS+Q4M2wh4CkojiJEMDCqNwiJrKdiqCxUTktERpyvyUDFDAIgAIQcEAA)

```ts
///// File: ../../../data/app.catalog.json
// Because you didn't share your actual JSON file, I'll make up a type
// to represent what TS infers it to be in a typical scenario:

type InferredJson = {
  id: string;
  props: {
    literal1: string;
    literal2: string;
    literal3: string;
    // etc...
  };
  // svg: string; // Let's say this isn't in your actual JSON
};


///// File: ./module.ts
// Instead of the actual import because this the playground doesn't support multiple files:
// import catalog from '../../../data/app.catalog.json';
declare const catalog: InferredJson;

// Won't work because of TS infers literal keys:
catalog.props.someProp = 'some value'; /*
              ^^^^^^^^
Property 'someProp' does not exist on type '{ literal1: string; literal2: string; literal3: string; }'.(2339) */

interface Variant {
  id: string;
  props: Record<string, string>;
  svg: string;
}

function assertIsType <T>(value: unknown): asserts value is T {}

assertIsType<Variant>(catalog);
catalog; // catalog is now type (InferredJson & Variant)
catalog.props.someProp = 'some value'; // ok

console.log(catalog.svg); // undefined
catalog.svg; // string, but this is a lie that you told the compiler, so act responsibly!
```

In summary:

```ts
import catalog from '../../../data/app.catalog.json';
import {assertIsType, type Variant} from './someModule';

assertIsType<Variant>(catalog); // Now it's (typeof catalog & Variant)
```

Comment: Interesting approach and it seems to work. However, is there no solution based on module augmentation?

Comment: @HarshalPatil I'm not sure whether there is or not, but I shared this approach because it maintains a layer of safety by having to make the assertion after the import (rather than simply overriding all type information inferred by the compiler).